# Laravel Eloquent use nested relationship to construct eloquent collection

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, eloquent-relationship

I would like to pull the record subscription detail record and the plans and cheats that the particular user subscribes. Aside from that, I also included all my relationship that is available in my model(s).

**User Model**

```php
// Columns: id, username, email

public function plans(){
    return $this->belongsToMany(Plan::class,"subscriptions","user_id","plan_id");
}
```

**Subscription Model**

```
// Columns: id, plan_id, user_id, expiry,dll_type
```

**Plan Model**

```php
// Columns: id, cheat_id, currency_code, country,amount

public function cheatinfo($val){
    return $this->hasOne(Cheat::class,'cheat_id','id');
}
```

**Cheats Model**

```php
// Columns: id, internal_subscription_name, cheat_name, isActive

public function plans(){
    return $this->hasMany(Plan::class)->select(['id','cheat_id','country','currency_code','amount']);
}
```

This is my attempt and this is my current function caller, by the way, I am new for Laravel Eloquent at the moment.

```php
User::whereId(2)->with(["plans"])->first();
```

**Current output**:

```json
{
    "resp": {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "qx.wong",
        "email": "user@gmail.com",
        "email_verified_at": null,
        "created_at": "2021-05-23T07:05:13.000000Z",
        "updated_at": "2021-05-23T07:05:13.000000Z",
        "plans": [
            {
                "id": 5,
                "country": "MY",
                "amount": 40,
                "currency_code": "MYR",
                "cheat_id": 3,
                "created_at": "2021-05-23T04:43:04.000000Z",
                "updated_at": "2021-05-23T04:43:04.000000Z",
                "pivot": {
                    "user_id": 2,
                    "plan_id": 5
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

**Expected output**:

```json
{
    "resp": {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "qx.wong",
        "email": "user@gmail.com",
        "email_verified_at": null,
        "created_at": "2021-05-23T07:05:13.000000Z",
        "updated_at": "2021-05-23T07:05:13.000000Z",
        "subscription": {
            "expiry":"2020-05-04",
            "dll_type":"2021",
            "plans":[
                {
                    "id": 5,
                    "country": "US",
                    "amount": 10,
                    "currency_code": "USD",
                    "cheat_id": 3,
                    "created_at": "2021-05-23T04:43:04.000000Z",
                    "updated_at": "2021-05-23T04:43:04.000000Z",
                    "pivot": {
                        "user_id": 2,
                        "plan_id": 5
                    },
                    "cheats":{
                        "id":3,
                        "internal_subscription_name":"pubg-ultimate-02",
                        "cheats_name":"PUBG Ultimate 2",
                        "isActive":1
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can access using nested relationship with dot operator like below

```
User::whereId(2)->with(["plans","palns.cheatinfo"])->first();
```